# How to find out cause of AppCrash?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, crash

On some machines my C# app crashes when started. How to find out what is the cause of the problem? Where to start my research?

When I get managed exceptions I have nice StackTrace and exception messages so I have good start point. But in AppCrash dialog there are some weird hex numbers, I don't know what they mean.

P.S. This machines do have appropriate .NET Framework installed.

**Update:** I'm not talking about specific exceptions, but rather about what are common methods of fixing those. I want to learn how to do it myself and not asking on forums about every error I encounter.

Comment: Posting the error would be helpful.

Comment: Write an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, log or trace the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString().

Answer (score 3):

I would look in the event viewer before starting looking at memory dumps etc. Many times it can be Graphic Cards drivers etc who causes the crash and the event viewer will then show what have happen.

Comment: Event viewer has a lot of categories. What should I look for?

Comment: Application and System would be the ones to look in

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at `windbg` to analyze the crash dump.

See this article for details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx

Answer (score 1):

At a blind guess I'd say you don't have the correct version of the .NET framework on the machine that is failing. Eg, you are trying to run a .net4 application on a machine where .net2 only is installed.

*How about posting a screenshot/text of the error?*

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried windbg with crashdump option ?.

so something like adplus –crash –sc c:\myfolder\Myapp.exe

You can find more details here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/anandbms/archive/2005/04/20/410225.aspx.